# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a version: 9

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, eclipse-oxygen

I am trying to run a [Spark maven Scala](https://github.com/opencypher/caps-examples) Project in eclipse .

when i run [the scala class](https://github.com/opencypher/caps-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/opencypher/example/HelloCypher.scala) , i get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a version: 9
at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.parts$1(Properties.scala:184)
at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.isJavaAtLeast(Properties.scala:187)
at scala.util.Properties$.isJavaAtLeast(Properties.scala:17)
....
```

what is wrong ? 
what is a version 9 ?

Comment: what scala version are you using?

Comment: the scala version is : **4.7.1**

Comment: that's your Scala IDE version. Check in the settings which JDK it is using.

Comment: where can i find it's settings in eclipse ? i find  under Scala Library Container folder in Manifest.mf this :Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6, JavaSE-1.7

Comment: what does your `java -version` typed in the console returns? What is JAVA_HOME and/or PATH set to with regards to Java? I had not used ScalaIDE... in Eclipse it's **Eclipse Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs**

Comment: java -version returns **java version "1.8.0_171"**.
JAVA_HOME is : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
In eclipse preferences I have a list of jre in **INSTALLED JRE** including jre 1.6 ,1.7 ,1.8 ,9 and others

Comment: you can follow [the steps done by the owner of the project before my last comment](https://github.com/opencypher/caps-examples/issues/2) to execute it. it works for him with eclipse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176258/discussion-between-a-haddad-and-diginoise).

Answer (score 2):

Scala does not work with Java 9 out of the box just yet - there is a way, but you have to be sure that various components in your mix have **minimal versions required for compatibility**.

See [this compatibility matrix](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html) (notice **Java**, **Scala** and **SBT** versions)

and [this issue for more details](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/139).

The easiest fix is to run your Spark project in Eclipse using **Java 8**.

Comment: I have JRE 1.8 **java version "1.8.0_171"**

Comment: This happens to me with java "1.8.0_212"